# (Python) There are no errors, but the program is not running

Tags: python

I need to calculate shipping costs based on package type, weight, and how many zones the delivery goes through. I didn't get all the hard numbers from him so I'm using some placements, but that shouldn't matter much. The problem is that even though no errors are listed, running the program only returns a blank page, no prompts to enter numbers or anything like that.

Here's the code.

```
def main():
    packageType = input('Please enter the package type: ')

    rate = 0
    zoneRate = 0

    if packageType == 1:
        rate += 1.25
    elif packageType == 2:
        rate += 1.5
    elif packageType == 3:
        rate += 1.75
    elif packageType == 4:
        rate += 2

    weight = input('Please enter the weight: ')

    if weight <= 2:
        rate += 3.10
    elif weight > 2 and weight <= 6:
        rate += 4.20
    elif weight > 6 and weight <= 10:
        rate += 5.30
    elif weight > 10:
        rate += 6.40

    zones = input('Please enter how many zones are crossed: ')

    if zones == 1:
        zoneRate += 5
    if zones == 2:
        zoneRate += 10
    if zones == 3:
        zoneRate += 15

    cost = rate * zoneRate
    print(('The shipping cost is: '), cost)
```

Comment: do you miss to call `main()` ?

Comment: because you didn't call  `main()`.

Comment: You should call the `main()` inorder to make it run

Comment: and remember to convert those `input()` into `int`, because by default those are strings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have

```
def main():
    # all of your code
    # goes here

main()
```

Comment: Or `if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()`